# std::map holding any value type

Tags: c++

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {

public:

    class MyFieldInterface
    {
      public:
        int m_Size;
        ~MyFieldInterface() = default;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class MyField : public MyFieldInterface {
      public:
           MyField(T val) {m_Value = val;}
           T m_Value; 
    };

    template <typename T>
    MyField<T>* getType(int type, T val) {
       if (type == 0) return new MyField<int>(val);
       if (type == 1) return new MyField<double>(val);
       if (type == 2) return new MyField<char>(val);
    }

    map<string, MyFieldInterface* > fields;  
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;

    obj.fields["a"] = obj.getType<int>(0, 1);
    obj.fields["b"] = obj.getType<double>(1, 1.1);
    obj.fields["c"] = obj.getType<char>(2, 'a');

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

I want `std::map` to hold any value type, thus I created a template class with dynamic inheritance.
 I have defined template class inside `MyClass` for the reason I don't want its definition to be exposed to user. Using `getType` function I will create a new object with given type which will be stored into the map.

With the above approach I get the below errors, I'm not able to succeed with the above approach.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘MyClass::MyField<T>* MyClass::getType(int, T) [with T = int]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',45)">main.cpp:45:44</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:34:53: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 1) return new MyField<double>(val);
                                                     ^
main.cpp:35:51: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 2) return new MyField<char>(val);
                                                   ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘MyClass::MyField<T>* MyClass::getType(int, T) [with T = double]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',46)">main.cpp:46:49</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:33:50: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 0) return new MyField<int>(val);
                                                  ^
main.cpp:35:51: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 2) return new MyField<char>(val);
                                                   ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘MyClass::MyField<T>* MyClass::getType(int, T) [with T = char]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',47)">main.cpp:47:47</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:33:50: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 0) return new MyField<int>(val);
                                                  ^
main.cpp:34:53: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::MyField*’ to ‘MyClass::MyField*’ in return
        if (type == 1) return new MyField<double>(val);
                                                     ^
```

Comment: That's not how templates work. No, C++ is a _statically_ typed language. Still, there is `std::any`. @edit A "right path" would be to differently model the problem you are doing using proper interfaces and inheritance

Comment: do you want `MyFieldInterface* getType(int,T)`?

Comment: If you're explicitly providing the templated type anyway, there's not reason to have to send some integral switch to specify the type. Just `return new MyField<T>(value)`;

Comment: I think the real question is "why do you need that"? It currently looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). C++ does not make it easy to avoid type system (which is good), so before you start you need to answer a question "isn't there a better way to solve my problem?"

Comment: Your `getType` should also be a static function, since it's not operating on any state of the instantiated object. No reason to pass the `this` pointer around. You probably want `static MyField<T>* getType(T val) {...` and `obj.fields["a"] = MyClass::getType<int>(1);`

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried to avoid passing templated type from `main` but was not successful.

Comment: @kiran no shame in passing a templated type. Explicitly specifying a template parameter for a static factory function actually looks really clean to me.

Comment: You don't need to pass the templated type in `main`. You are already using a parameter from which the type can be deduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a run-time parameter to choose between multiple types. You need to decide what type is returned at compile time. But this is exactly what templates are for, so you could simply do:

```
template <typename T>
MyField<T>* getType(T val) {
   return new MyField<T>(val);
}
```

and then use the function like this:

```
obj.fields["a"] = obj.getType(1);
obj.fields["b"] = obj.getType(1.1);
obj.fields["c"] = obj.getType('a');
```

Note that you don't need to specify `T` at the call site, since that can be deduced from the function argument.

Of course, you will need to keep track of what type each key in the map refers to separately.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YoEx9C).

Also, the way this function is implemented, the name `getType` is confusing, since you are not actually returning a type here. Perhaps a better name would be `getAnyPointer`.

Comment: Calling something that returns a pointer to an object "getType" is very confusing